# filemaker pro export and import to mysql via php

Tags: mysql, xml, migration, filemaker

could anyone advise me direct me to a site that explains the best way to go about this I'm sure I could figure it out with allot of time invested but just looking for a jump start. I don't want to use the migration tool either as I just want to put fmp xml files on the server and it create new MySql databases based on the fmpxml results provided

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can write a XSLT to transform the XML files into SQL. It's pretty much straightforward for data (except data in container fields), but with some effort you can even transfer the scheme from DDR reports (but I doubt it worth it for a single project).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MySQL? v6 has `LOAD XML` which will make things easy for you.

If not v6, then you are dealing with stored procedures, which can be a pain. If you need v5, it might make sense to install MySQL6, get the data in there using LOAD XML, and then do a mysqldump, which you can import into v5.

Here is a good link:
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html